# Performance gain from CSS display:none or $.remove()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) for a foreign website. It has many scripts and ads that I want to remove. I have two files in my extension, a CSS and a JS file. In CSS file, I hide these elements:

```
/* Hide some parts before removing them */
aside,
#site-footer,
.ads,
iframe,
script {
  display: none
}
```

And in JS file I remove them with jQuery:

```
// List of selectors to remove
var removeList = [
  'aside',
  '#site-footer',
  '.ads',
  'iframe',
  'script'
];
// Remove them
$(removeList.join(",")).remove();
```

I realised that hiding elements using CSS is much faster than jQuery.remove() function. My question is that, do I really need removing these elements after hiding with CSS? Can there be any performance when I remove them from DOM? I mean, for example, do iframes still use CPU after `display:none`? If so I should continue using JS code. Otherwise what potential gains can offer this extra removal?

Comment: anything jQuery does is measurably slower than native DOM methods - as you're using firefox, you can use the following code to remove jQuery requirement for at least the remove part of your code: `document.querySelectorAll(removeList.join(",")).forEach(e => e.remove())`

Comment: The answer is "its depends"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I decided to use both `display:none` and `$.remove()`. After hiding, maybe the browser doesn't create the visual data form scratch but it makes all the rest. For example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X18mUlDddCc?autoplay=1" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Music plays on the page using Firefox v53. It does load all the HTML/JS/CSS files. So the perfomance gain of the `display:none` is really questionable in this case. I also need to remove the element.

Although it's slow to remove elements from DOM, it's still the best option for me. Maybe not for the static data but for elements like `iframe`, `.ads` (they usually contain iframes) it's a must. Still, I can try to use pure JS instead of jQuery for a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Property `display:none` only hiding your element but not deleting from DOM. And all your iframes will still use CPU after this, because CSS controls only how element shows on screen.